# Generating number Sequence Python

Tags: python, range, sequence

I want to generate a number sequence that repeats 2 consective numbers twice then skips a number and repeats the sequence wihin the range specified.

such as

0,0,1,1,3,3,4,4,6,6,7,7 and so forth.

what I have so far

```
numrange = 10
numsequence  = [i for i in range(numrange) for _ in range(2)]
numsequence
```

which produces

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9]
```

which is close but not quite what I want

Comment: @NIKUNJPATEL your first sequence, like i posted in my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate over numbers with the step 3:

```
[i + j for i in range(0, numrange, 3) for j in (0, 0, 1, 1)]
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6, 7, 7, 9, 9, 10, 10]
```

Comment: Yep, that's another way. Probably easier to adapt to other patterns than mine.

Comment: Hmm, they said "wihin the range" and their own attempt uses `range(numrange)`. But your output shows you include `10`, which isn't within the range.

Comment: @KellyBundy That's the question of the business logic that OP didn't specify. My solution assumes an inclusive range. To make it exclusive we'd just use `range(0, numrange - 1, 3)` instead, but that would leave out `3, 3` as well because otherwise `3` wouldn't have its consecutive partner (*... repeats 2 consecutive numbers twice ...*).

Answer (score 3):

```py
[i+i//2 for i in range(2*(numrange+1)//3) for _ in range(2)]
```

Is one on the many ways to do it. This one is probably the closest to your attempt.

Comment: Yes it does. On my computer, result is `[0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6, 7, 7, 9, 9, 10, 10, 12, 12, 13, 13]`.

Comment: Right. Sorry, my error. Nice solution then!

Comment: @chrslg this works well.  I also need the sequence to stop at the numrange. I didnt realise this would also need to be stipulated. I tought it would stop at the the number as opposed to making that many numbers

Comment: @Spooked this will stop at `numrange` if you use `range(numrange - 2)` instead (or `range(numrange - 3)` if you need it exclusive)

Comment: @Spooked Corrected so that it gives all numbers of that pattern that are smaller than numrange

Comment: But that is another reason why @YevhenKuzmovych solution is more flexible. It is easier, for any kind of repetitive patter, both to design the pattern, and secondly to know when to stop :D

Comment: @chrslg thanks for the update.  are you able to explain how the // works?

Comment: `//` is just integer division. `a//b` is roughly the same as `int(a/b)`. Except that `int(a/b)` do perform a floating point division, using floating points instruction of the CPU, and with the uncertainties of floating points (For example the fact that `int(4 - 10*(2/10 + 1/10))` is 0). While `a//b` use integer instructions. But outside convoluted fabricated examples made to show differences, `a//b` has the same result as `int(a/b)`. So `10//2` is 5. `13//2` is 6. And therefor `i+i//2` is 0 when i is 0, 1 when i=1, since 1//2 is 0. 3 when i=2, because 2//2=1. Etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can make yours work simply by inserting `if ~i % 3` (or `if i % 3 < 2`, but where's the fun it that :-). Reformatted for easier reading:

```
numrange = 10
numsequence = [
    i
    for i in range(numrange)
    if ~i % 3
    for _ in range(2)
]
print(numsequence)
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P680tygxLz1VwVbB0IALyCtOLSxNzUsGCURzKQBBJphMyy9SyFTIzFMAq9aAadOEKElTqMtUUFUwhiuNRyg10uSK5Sooyswr0UAyXvP/fwA)):

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6, 7, 7, 9, 9]
```